# Link between Bessel and spherical Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

I have some trouble understanding how to pass from bessel function to spherical bessel function.
Departing  from  the  Helmholtz differential equation:

$   \begin{equation}
r^2 \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial r^2} +2r \frac{\partial R}{\partial r} +\left[ k^2 r^2 - m(m+1)\right]R =0\text{.}
\label{eq:zap1}
\end{equation}$

Then using the change of function $R(r)=\frac{Z(r)}{(kr)^{1/2}} $, it's possible to find :
$Z" r^{2} + Z' r  +\left[ k^2 r^2 - (m+1/2)^2\right]Z=0$.

Thus the solution using the bessel equation is : 
$R(r)= A\frac{J_{m+1/2}(kr)}{\sqrt{kr}}+B\frac{Y_{m+1/2}(kr)}{\sqrt{kr}}$.

The general solution is  known as the spherical bessel function :
$R(r)= A'j_{m}(kr)+B'y_{m}(kr)$,

avec :

$j_{m}(z)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{J_{m+1/2}(z)}{\sqrt{z}} $ et $y_{m}(z)= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{Y_{m+1/2}(z)}{\sqrt{z}} $.

So where this $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ come from ?

(The details of the equations are in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselDifferentialEquation.html)

Comment: Would you accept, that the factor $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ is just a convention to have nice explicite expressions? E.g. $$j_0(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$$
$$j_1(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}-\frac{\cos(z)}{z}$$
$$\dots$$

Comment: The factor $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is just convention, makes other formulae neater

Comment: @gammatester So in the end it's just a multiplicative constant which doesn't change anything aside making the writting neater ?